# Should I read Neil Gaiman's mini-series first?

Tags: suggested-order, neil-gaiman, vertigo-comics, books-of-magic

I have some back issues of the main [Books of Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_Magic#Ongoing_series) series, however I don't have the Neil Gaiman mini-series that preceded it.

Does reading the mini-series first add value to the main series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Neil Gaiman created the character and explains the "magic" in the DC Universe, I would say yes, it adds immense value. The John Boltan (and others) art is also a nice addition. I would also read the 4-issue mini-series *The Trenchcoat Brigade* at some point as it revisits the original mini-series. It's not as important when you read the 2nd mini, though, if memory serves. It's a self-contained series and not necessarily between certain issues of the on-going series.